# CoreData saving array

Tags: arrays, swift

i am trying to save array in coreData and then use it in code, so, i have a model:

```
class InsultsModel {
    
    var savedInsultsData: [Insults] = []
    
}
```

And i have coreData Manager

```
class CoreDataManager: CoreDataManagerProtocol {
    
    var insults: InsultsModel
    
    required init(insults: InsultsModel) {
        self.insults = insults
    }
    
    func saveInsult(insult: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Insults", in: context) else { return }
        
        let insultObject = Insults(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        insultObject.insult = insult
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            self.insults.savedInsultsData.append(insultObject)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchInsult() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Insults> = Insults.fetchRequest()
        
        do {
            self.insults.savedInsultsData = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteInsult(savedData: NSManagedObject) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Insults> = Insults.fetchRequest()
        
        do {
            self.insults.savedInsultsData = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            context.delete(savedData)
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Actually i realized adding data, remove dat and fetch data

When i am trying to use it in code i have problem what coreData Model is NSObject, but i set it as String in Core Data Settings

```
func previousInsult() -> String {
        if self.index > 0 {
            self.index -= 1
        }
        print("index \(index)")
        print(self.coreData.insults.savedInsultsData.count)
        return self.insults.savedInsultsData[self.index]
    }
```

error is "Cannot convert return expression of type 'Insults' to return type 'String'"

Comment: `Insults` is a class and not an attribute, I assume it has some attribute(s) that you want to use instead. If I read the code correctly it has an attribute `insult` so maybe return `self.insults.savedInsultsData[self.index].insult`?

Comment: you should create id property in coredata entity 
store unique value in id . then save your array in userdefault with key that id property and also get that array with that id key

Comment: Thank you very much! elf.insults.savedInsultsData[self.index].insult! This works, i thought that if i cast the coredata string i already have the string